# How to increase weight range avaliable when using Tabledrag?

Tags: forms, javascript

I have a tabledrag with more than 20 entries. Much more. Default weight range is from -10 to +10, so it can only order first 20 entries. Every additional one have weight of 10 and is ordered by secondary means like ID, name or whatever, and not the way user set it to. How can I expand that range? I can't see anything like that in [drupal_add_tabledrag](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!common.inc/function/drupal_add_tabledrag/7) documentation.

My form definition is pretty much copy-paste from [Examples for Developers](https://drupal.org/project/examples).

Comment: It definitely should be possible too because I have seen tables with a wider range of weights than that.

Comment: check this https://drupal.org/node/117274

Comment: @rooby I believe it *is* possible. My problem is that I don't know how and can't find it now. Probably I'm mind-blind or something... I feel really bad about asking so "stupid" question.

Comment: @Bala It's Drupal 6, I'm it 7, and it seems it is not possible? Buth both rooby and I have seen it working. Just can't access the code.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using a field of type "weight" like in the examples module you need to use the [#delta](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer!topics!forms_api_reference.html/7#delta) attribute.

Comment: Right, thanks. I knew it's obvious (once you remember it...) 2 minutes to accept ;)